# Fast solution to widen adjacency list for triangle mesh

Tags: python, optimization, set, mesh, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency list of 3D triangle mesh vertices which contains indices of adjacent vertices for every vertex represented as a list of sets. Sets can vary in size since a vertex can have a variable number of adjacent vertices.

```py
# example

vertices = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.75, 2],    # vertex 0
    [0.35, 0.7, 1],    # vertex 1
    [0.15, 0.3, 0.5],  # vertex 2
    ...
    [0, 0.5, 0.3],     # vertex M
])

adjacency_list = np.array([
    {0, 1, 2, ...},  # vertex 0's adjacent vertices
    {4, 5, 6, ...},  # vertex 1's adjacent vertices
    ...
    {9, 15, 4, ...}  # vertex M's adjacent vertices
], dtype=object)
```

and I want to expand every set of the list with indices of vertices within area defined by N rings constructed around every vertex as illustrated below (only example, not related to the example code) such that the adjacency set of vertex V contains all indices from N rings around it.

[image: vertex V and N adjacent rings around it]

I tried a recursive approach but this is really slow (~200ms for N=3 for each vertex) and I'm having trouble figuring out the optimal solution. Also, I feel like this task should not be very uncommon but I haven't come across anything meaningful. Feel free to redirect me to another thread if it is related.

Comment: can you edit your post to explain your numbering system a bit?  It isn't clear how you are counting only 3 vertices from each vertex or how they are numbered.  The green vertices, for example, appear to have 6 adjacent nodes...

Comment: Edited the post, hope it's more clear now. The code and the figure are just individual examples. Adjacency set for vertex V on the figure would have 6 indices as you pointed out.

Comment: We're getting there...  but your numbering system is not clear.  Where is vertex #4?  Are they numbered in a spiral or top to bottom or what?

Comment: Also, you are using N in two contexts.  You say an "N-sized ring" which I *assume* is the number of nodes in the ring?  And then you say "N rings" that needs cleanup too.

Comment: ok, I think I see what you mean, edited now, let me know if anything else is unclear

Comment: Using `object`-typed array items unfortunately defeats the benefits of using Numpy. The recursive approach is not bad, but using CPython for that is not great for performance. Consider using Cython or even native languages. Btw, networkx may help you for such algorithm (looking like a BFS).

Comment: Downward relations (like cell -> point) are easy to construct and store, upward relations (like point -> cell) are hard to construct and store. I've worked with meshes for a while and my recommendation would be to think twice or three times if you really need this information. In my experience, there's (almost) always a better way.